# For what values of of $p$ does the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{cos(pn\pi)}{\sqrt{n}+4}$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am given a series:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{cos(pn\pi)}{\sqrt{n}+4}$$

where $p \in \mathbb{Z}$

And am told to find for which values of $p$ will the series converge.

Since $cosine$ alternates between $0,1$ and $-1$, the series can be written as:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^{pn}}{\sqrt{n}+4}$$

Which is an alternating series where $a_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+4}$, for $p \in\mathbb{Z}$.

Using the Alternating Series Test:

1. $a_{n}>0$ for all $n\geq 1$ (a positive term series)
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=0$ using the Standard Limit: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\frac{1}{n^b})=0$ where $b>0$
3. $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ (a decreasing series)

Thus, $a_n$ converges according to the Alternating Series Test.

Hence my answer is that the series converges for all integer values of $p$. Is this correct?

Comment: Cosine equals a lot more values than just -1, 0, and 1.

Comment: Its a hard problem ....not that trivial...

Comment: Forgot to add in that p is an integer

Comment: Is it just that if $p$ is even, the series is positive and diverges while if $p$ is odd, it's a damping oscillation so it converges?

Comment: For $p \in \mathbb{R}$, use partial summation to make $\sum_{n =1}^N \cos(\pi p n)$ appear (aka. Dirichlet test)

Comment: That's beyond the scope of my course.

Comment: When $p$ is even, and you need to prove that it diverges.  When $p$ is odd, then it will alternative, and your argument should work.

Comment: Why does it diverge when $p$ is even?

Comment: You could use a limit comparison test with sum of $n^{-1/2}$.